# Run go web application on IIS

Tags: iis, go

Is there a way to run Go web application on IIS?
I found a setting for azure but its not working on my dev machine
this is a web config for azure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="d:\home\site\wwwroot\go\bin\go.exe" 
                      arguments="run d:\home\site\wwwroot\server.go" 
                      startupTimeLimit="60">
            <environmentVariables>
              <environmentVariable name="GOROOT" value="d:\home\site\wwwroot\go" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You'll have to reverse proxy from IIS to the port your Go application is listening on: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis

Comment: Go also has a [FastCGI responder implementation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/fcgi/) and with IIS 7+ a Go server using FastCGI backend [can be run as a FCGI application](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis).  Note that the FastCGI responder is rumored to be somewhat slower than HTTP's so it *might* be more performant to do reverse HTTP proxying as @elithrar suggests. Note that your Go server may well listen to HTTP and FCGI requests simultaneously.

Comment: Go's FastCGI server is objectively slower, so I wouldn't recommend it. I'd have to dig up the benchmarks, but the Go team has admitted it hasn't seen a lot of perf. tuning due to low demand.

Comment: plus, FastCGI is a relic from before HTTP/1.1, which provides most of the same benefits. There's very few reasons to use FastCGI, unless it's your only option.

Comment: I just want to test my app on local IIS. Because I don't have access to Linux server and I can't change my OS

Comment: Then there's no reason to use IIS at all, unless you have it serving other assets required by your app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your local IIS does not work simply because you need to install a separate component, called [HttpPlatformHandler module](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/announcing-the-release-of-the-httpplatformhandler-module-for-iis-8/).

Reverse proxy or FastCGI were the older approaches which are no longer necessary with this new approach.

I wrote [a post with examples and troubleshooting tips](https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-go-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/) to show how things can work together.

About why **you shouldn't use ASP.NET Core module**, [you can read the history here](https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/).

Answer (score 8):

HttpPlatformHandler module doesn't work for me. I found [this post by Sutean Rutjanalard on Medium](https://medium.com/@mossila/running-go-behind-iis-ce1a610116df) very helpful, which use ASP.NET Core Module instead.

Basically, you need to create Application pool with "No Managed Code" as you do with a .net core app. And the following is the web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath=".\YourGoApp.exe" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, I start from this question as well.

Comment: @Mossila You are welcome. I thought this may help somebody else. Glad it's helpful to you too.

Comment: Yes, I wrote this article after I pain from finding the right way to do it for week!.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that you are the author. I should thank you then :)

Comment: Small addition, for .net core 3+ versions you need to specify AspNetCoreModuleV2, not AspNetCoreModule

Comment: "Doesn't work" is too vague, not even an error message.